# Why is my selfie flipped?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I take a picture, facing front, and I get a reduplication of the reality in front of my with the right and left sides equivalent between earth and digital. However, once I step over to take a selfie picture reality gets reversed on the digital end, right to left and left to right. Why?

Comment: The theory is that it's like looking in a mirror, less confusing if you're using it as such. I've no official citation for that, so just as a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While taking the selfie, **the displayed image is mirrored so you can line things up easier**. This is demonstrated in the first image.

After the photo is taken, the image is unmirrored and displayed naturally. This is demonstrated in the second image.

[image: Screenshot of selfie camera]
[image: Image that was taken]

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by what you mean by reality getting reversed. It may help if you provide pictures.

Possible scenarios:
You may be changing the orientation of your device causing your camera to assume which way is up and down.
Or
You may have a orientation lock on your device as a whole, that is affecting the camera
Or 
You might just be seeing your self from the view/ direction that your camera sees you.

Answer (score 0):

In actual your selfie isn't fliped by Apple, in fact Apple is probably one of the very few Makers who keeps it the way it should be. But, even still if you want to change the selfie mirroring, then there are plenty of apps on AppStore as well. I am providing link for one of them . [Mirror Selfie App](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/mirror-put-on-make-up-check/id379516970)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [answer] for tips on providing good answers and avoiding downvotes.  Your answer doesn't add any additional info and just restates what other answers already provided.

Comment: @fsb yes I understand that's why I added a link for him as a part of solution to the problem he is facing. I hope this one qualifies as a good answer than previous attempt of myself.